# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException en programa Java

Tags: java

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en **Java Netbeans** con base de datos **phpMyAdmin**.
Ya he elaborado algunas más, pero ahora se me ha presentado este problema:

Dicha aplicación sirve para capturar datos de un almacén que lleva un control de entradas y salidas de papelería, así como de material eléctrico y herramientas que se tienen que dar de baja y las que no, crearen un inventario donde se incluye marca, modelo y en ocasiones el número de serie; captura todo en los respectivos campos y realiza un par de operaciones aritméticas, el detalles es que cuando presiono el botón Guardar me indica esta serie de líneas:

> run: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   almacen.Insumos.cboarticuloActionPerformed(Insumos.java:616)  at
>   almacen.Insumos.access$000(Insumos.java:12)   at
>   almacen.Insumos$1.actionPerformed(Insumos.java:164)   at
>   javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1260)    at
>   javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:588)     at
>   almacen.Insumos.btnguardarActionPerformed(Insumos.java:688)   at
>   almacen.Insumos.access$200(Insumos.java:12)   at
>   almacen.Insumos$3.actionPerformed(Insumos.java:183)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Siendo estas líneas el código correspondiente:

```
package almacen;
import java.sql.Connection;
/*import Conexion.Conectar;*/
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel; 

public class Insumos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DefaultTableModel modelo;

    public Insumos() {
        initComponents();   
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelo.addColumn("Articulo");
        modelo.addColumn("Stock");
        modelo.addColumn("Cantidad Solicitada");
        modelo.addColumn("Unidad");
        modelo.addColumn("Marca");
        modelo.addColumn("Modelo");
        modelo.addColumn("Usuario");
        modelo.addColumn("Extensión Cisco");
        modelo.addColumn("Unidad Administrativa");
        modelo.addColumn("MOvimiento");
        this.tblinsumos.setModel(modelo);
                      }


    /*void CargarTablaDatos(String valor) {
        String[] titulos = {"Articulo", "Stock", "Cantidad Solicitada", "Unidad", "Marca", "Modelo", "Usuario", "Extensión Cisco", "Unidad Administrativa", "Movimiento"};
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
        String[] registro = new String[18];
        Conexion mysql = new Conexion();
        Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();
        String sSQL;

        sSQL = "SELECT Articulo, Stock, Cantidad_Solicitada, Unidad, Marca, Modelo, Usuario, Extension_Cisco, Movimiento FROM insumos "
                + "WHERE CONCAT(Usuario, ' ', Extension_Cisco, ' ', Unidad_Administrativa, ' ')LIKE '%" + valor + "%'";
        try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

            int c = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                registro[0] = rs.getString("Articulo");
                registro[1] = rs.getString("Stock");
                registro[2] = rs.getString("Cantidad_Solicitada");
                registro[3] = rs.getString("Unidad");
                registro[4] = rs.getString("Marca");
                registro[5] = rs.getString("Modelo");
                registro[6] = rs.getString("Usuario");
                registro[7] = rs.getString("Extension_Cisco");
                registro[8] = rs.getString("Unidad_Administrativa");
                registro[9] = rs.getString("Movimiento");
                modelo.addRow(registro);
                c++;
            }
            tblinsumos.setModel(modelo);        //variable de la tabla
           this. tblinsumos.setModel(modelo);        //variable de la tabla
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }*/

    public void FormatoConsulta(){
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(10);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(50);
        tblinsumos.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(50);
                                 }

void BuscarDatosEditar(String id){
        String sSQL;

        String art="", stk="", cantsol="", unit="", mrc="", mod="", user="" ;
        String extcisco="", uadmva="",mov="";

        Conexion mysql = new Conexion();
        Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();

        sSQL = "SELECT Articulo, Stock, Cantidad_Solicitada, Unidad. Marca, Modelo, Usuario, "+
                "SELECT Extension_Cisco, Unidad_Administrativa, Movimiento FROM insumos"+
                "WHERE Articulo = "+id;

      try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

            while(rs.next()){
                art = rs.getString("Articulo");
                stk = rs.getString("Stock");
                cantsol = rs.getString("Cantidad_Solicitada");
                unit = rs.getString("Unidad");
                mrc = rs.getString("Marca");
                mod = rs.getString("Modelo");
                user = rs.getString("Usuario");
                extcisco = rs.getString("Extension_Cisco");
                uadmva = rs.getString("Unidad_Administrativa");
                mov = rs.getString("Movimiento");
                            }
            }catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
}  

    private void btnborrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
            btnborrar.transferFocus();
            txtstockA.setText("");
            txtcantsol.setText("");
            txtmodelo.setText("");
            txtext_c.setText("");
    }                                         

    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        Menu mn = new Menu();
        mn.setVisible(true);
    }                                             

    private void txtcantsolActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        txtcantsol.transferFocus();
    }                                          

    private void txtext_cActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        txtext_c.transferFocus();    }                                        

    private void txtmodeloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        txtmodelo.transferFocus();
    }                                         

    private void btnuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        btnuevo.transferFocus();
        cboarticulo.setSelectedItem("");
        txtstockA.setText("");
        txtcantsol.setText("");
        cbounidad.setSelectedItem("");
        cbomarca.setSelectedItem("");
        txtmodelo.setText("");
        cbouser.setSelectedItem("");
        txtext_c.setText("");        
        txtuadmva.setText("");        
        cbomov.setSelectedItem("");
    }                                       

    private void cbomovActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        cbomov.transferFocus();
    }                                      

    private void cboarticuloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        cboarticulo.transferFocus();

                  String aeropuerto = cboarticulo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (aeropuerto.equals("León Mata Jesús Arturo"))  {
                txtstockA.setText("");  
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("2"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("3"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("4"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("5"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
                }else if(aeropuerto.equals("6"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("7"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("8"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }else if(aeropuerto.equals("9"))   {
                txtstockA.setText("");
            }
    }                                           

    private void txtstockAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        txtstockA.transferFocus();
    }                                         

    private void cbounidadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        cbounidad.transferFocus();
    }                                         

    private void cbomarcaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        cbomarca.transferFocus();
    }                                        

    private void cbouserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        cbouser.transferFocus();
                  String usuario = cbouser.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (usuario.equals("León Mata Jesús Arturo"))  {
                txtext_c.setText("18679");  
                txtuadmva.setText("CIAAC");
            }else if(usuario.equals("2"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("18300");
                txtuadmva.setText("Área Central");
            }else if(usuario.equals("3"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("007");
                txtuadmva.setText("Almacen");
            }else if(usuario.equals("4"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("18300");
                txtuadmva.setText("Dirección de Control");
            }else if(usuario.equals("5"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("007");
                txtuadmva.setText("Dirección de Verificación");
                }else if(usuario.equals("6"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("18300");
                txtuadmva.setText("Licencias");
            }else if(usuario.equals("7"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("007");
                txtuadmva.setText("Terminal 1");
            }else if(usuario.equals("8"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("18300");
                txtuadmva.setText("Terminal 2");
            }else if(usuario.equals("9"))   {
                txtext_c.setText("007");
                txtuadmva.setText("CIAAC");

            }
    }                                       

                /* String accion = "Insertar";*/
    private void btnguardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String []Datos = new String[10];
        Datos[0] = cboarticulo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cboarticulo.setSelectedItem(null);
        Datos[1] = txtstockA.getText();
        txtstockA.setText(null);
        Datos[2] = txtcantsol.getText();
        txtcantsol.setText(null);
        Datos[3] = cbounidad.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cbounidad.setSelectedItem(null);
        Datos[4] = cbomarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cbomarca.setSelectedItem(null);
        Datos[5] = txtmodelo.getText();
        txtmodelo.setText(null);
        Datos[6] = cbouser.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cbouser.setSelectedItem(null);
        Datos[7] = txtext_c.getText();
        txtext_c.setText(null);
        Datos[8] = txtuadmva.getText();
        txtuadmva.setText(null);
        Datos[9] = cbomov.getSelectedItem().toString();
        cbomov.setSelectedItem(null);
        modelo.addRow(Datos);

        /*cbomov.transferFocus();*/
    /*    Conexion mysql = new Conexion();
        Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();
        String desc, stk, cantsol, unit, mrc, mod, user, extcisco, mov;
        String sSQL;
        String mensaje;
        desc = cboarticulo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        stk = txtstockA.getText();
        cantsol = txtcantsol.getText();
        unit=cbounidad.getSelectedItem().toString();
        mrc=cbomarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
        mod=txtmodelo.getText();
        user=cbouser.getSelectedItem().toString();
        extcisco=txtext_c.getText();
        mov=cbomov.getSelectedItem().toString();

        sSQL = "INSERT INTO insumos(Articulo, Stock, Cantidad_Solicitada, "+
               "Unidad, Marca, Modelo, Usuario, Extension_Cisco, Movimiento, "+
               "VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            mensaje = "Datos insertados exitosamente";

                try {
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
            pst.setString(1,desc);
            pst.setString(2,stk);
            pst.setString(3,cantsol);
            pst.setString(4,unit);
            pst.setString(5,mrc);
            pst.setString(6,mod);
            pst.setString(7,user);
            pst.setString(8,extcisco);
            pst.setString(9,mov);

            int n = pst.executeUpdate();


            if (n > 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
            }       

        }catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }  */ 
    }                                          

    private void btnentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;


        num1 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtstockA.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtcantsol.getText());

        int saldo = num1 + num2;

/*        txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); */
        txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo));
         /*txtcantres.setText(null);*/
        txtcantres.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); 



        /*num1 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtstockA.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtcantsol.getText());

        int saldo = num1 + num2;*/

/*        txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); */
        /*txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo));
        txtcantres.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); */
    }                                      

    private void btnsalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;

         num1 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtstockA.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtcantsol.getText());

        int saldo = num1 - num2;
        txtcantres.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); 
         /*txtcantres.setText(null);*/
        txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo));

 /*       num1 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtstockA.getText());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(this.txtcantsol.getText());

        int saldo = num1 - num2;
        txtcantres.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); 
        txtstockA.setText(String.valueOf(saldo)); */

    }                                      

    private void txtuadmvaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        txtuadmva.transferFocus();
    }                                         

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void txtBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
         txtBuscar.transferFocus();
    }                                         

    private void txtcantresActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        txtcantres.transferFocus();
    }                                          
 /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Insumos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Insumos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Insumos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Insumos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Insumos().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnborrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnent;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnguardar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnmodificar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnsal;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnuevo;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cboarticulo;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cbomarca;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cbomov;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cbounidad;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox cbouser;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblinsumos;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtcantres;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtcantsol;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtext_c;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtmodelo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtstockA;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtuadmva;
    // End of variables declaration                   

  /*  private void CargarTablaDatos(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }*/
}
```

Ya revisé todas las líneas y rediseñe el formulario varias veces y sucede esto, no se cómo solucionar estos detalles.

Comment: Jesus, recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para mejorar tu pregunta y hacerla mas atrayente a los usuario.

Comment: obviamente el problema esta aca: String aeropuerto = cboarticulo.getSelectedItem().toString();.. y si quieres saber porque, te convendria leer la siguiente pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-soluci%C3%B3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados

Comment: Según la excepción, el error lo tienes en el método cbouserActionPerformed. Como te ha dicho @gbianchi, solo en esa línea te puede dar ese error. Tampoco es nada "elegante" eso de poner a null los  combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo phpmyadmin no es una base de datos o motor de base de datos, es un gestor de base de datos, y por lo que veo en el método de `btnguardarActionPerformed`
primero obtienes el valor, y luego lo seteas a `NULL`

```
txtcantsol.setText(null)
```

Cuando dentro del objeto debe llevar el valor que le indicas en el arreglo, como lo seteas a `null`, te va a dar un `java.lang.nullpointer exception`. Revisa tu código y asígnale el valor que obtienes de bien sea la base de datos o interfaz gráfica.